# OneDrive Delta Next Page Link Error

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to page through deltas for a OneDrive root folder, but the second page is giving me a link that returns a 400 error.

My initial request looks like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/<drive-id>/root/microsoft.graph.delta
```

which returns a page of deltas and a link to the next page.

The next page link looks like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives('<drive-id>')/root/microsoft.graph.delta(token='MzslMjMzOyUyMzE7Mzs5ZmY3MzExYy0yYzRmLTQwZGMtYmVjNS0zMWI3NDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXk0OTMyNDMwMDAwOzkxMjY5ODk3OyUyM1BhZ2VkPVRSVUUlMjZwX0lEPTI1NTg7JTIzOyUyMzQ')
```

But when I make a request using that link, I get this response:

```
400 : Bad Request
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Transfer-Encoding : chunked
Strict-Transport-Security : max-age=31536000
Cache-Control : private
x-ms-ags-diagnostic : {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West US","Slice":"SliceA","Ring":"4","ScaleUnit":"000","Host":"AGSFE_IN_27","ADSiteName":"WST"}}
client-request-id : 5c1d0d11-1c1f-4fa0-8c1e-ce61369402ce
Duration : 11.1016
request-id : 5c1d0d11-1c1f-4fa0-8c1e-ce61369402ce
Date : Thu, 29 Mar 2018 23:14:01 GMT
Content-Type : application/json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Syntax error at position 160 in \u0027token\u003d\u0027MzslMjMzOyUyMzE7Mzs5ZmY3MzExYy0yYzRmLTQwZGMtYmVjNS0zMWI3NDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXk0OTMyNDMwMDAwOzkxMjY5ODk3OyUyM1BhZ2VkPVRSVUUlMjZwX0lEPTI1NTg7JTIzOyUyMzQ\u0027)(token\u003dnull\u0027.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "5c1d0d11-1c1f-4fa0-8c1e-ce61369402ce",
      "date": "2018-03-29T23:14:01"
    }
  }
}
```

This looks like it's probably an internal problem, but maybe I'm doing something wrong. I've tried with both the beta and v1.0 endpoints. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URI is close but not correct. The [correct URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_delta#http-request) should be:

```
GET /drives/{drive-id}/root/delta
```

Comment: Unfortunately /delta gives me the same response. The next page link that comes back still points to /microsoft.graph.delta, and that link still gives me the same response, even if I modify it to /delta.

Comment: I'm struggling to reproduce this. The error seems to imply there is a Unicode problem (`\u0027` is Unicode for `'`). Is it possible you're switching the charset from the `utf-8` that Graph is returning?

Comment: I believe what I'm sending is in the right encoding. I think the unicode might just be escaped in the error message. I am able to retrieve multiple delta pages for /users, although the next page links for those are formatted differently, with a $skiptoken URL parameter. The token seems to be much longer in that case, too. Are the drive next-link tokens that you get as short as the ones I'm seeing?

Comment: Mine look very similar. Each endpoint handles delta tokens at the service level so AAD handles `/users` and SharePoint handles `/drives`. It isn't surprising that there would be differences between them.

Comment: I think you're right, my client might be affecting the encoding somehow. I extracted the next link URL and made the call through a separate REST client, and got a valid response. Thank you for your help.